remove display style using if statement
So I want to remove the style, when valueCounts[trueBitValue] does not appear at least 3 times, styleKeepHolding should be removed. How the program works: I send a standard frame to communicate with the device. The device returns a message to me if I press a button on the device, the 4th and 3rd bytes change depending on which button is pressed.
As I wrote earlier, if I press a button, let's say it's a 12-byte, the first thing I do is decode that value by calculating 4 and 3 bytes, as it is in the code. Then I compare it with the byte in my img with data-bit-value attribute to specify which button (from app view) should get style.
I've tried so many statements and none of them worked...
I'm using modbus frames to sent and receive signals
Here is how the app works:

<li> 
    <p class="bit-value-text"></p>
    <img src="shield_up.png" alt="" data-bit-value="12">
</li>
<li>
    <p class="bit-value-text"></p>
    <img src="right_arm_up.png" alt="" data-bit-value="6">
</li>
<li>
    <p class="bit-value-text"></p>
    <img src="left_arm_down.png" alt="" data-bit-value="1">
</li>


function startInterval() {
  let i = 1;

  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
      stoper++;
      if (stoper <= 10) {       
        let arrayValues = tablica;
        const bajt4 = arrayValues[4];
        const bajt3 = arrayValues[3];
        bit = bajt4 + (bajt3 << 8);
        let trueBitValue = getBaseLog(2, bit);
        console.log(trueBitValue);
        imgBitValue.forEach(pair => {

        if (trueBitValue === pair.bitValue) {
          currentButton.src = pair.imgSrc;
          pair.previousSibling.innerHTML = i;
          styleKeepHolding(pair);

          if (valueCounts[trueBitValue]) {
            i++;
            pair.previousSibling.innerHTML = i;
            valueCounts[trueBitValue]++;
          } else {
            valueCounts[trueBitValue] = 1;
          }

            if (valueCounts[trueBitValue] >= 3) {
              styleCorrectElement(pair);
              
            }
            
          } else if (trueBitValue === -Infinity) {
            // styleResetElement(pair);
            valueCounts = [];
            i = 1;
          }          
          
        });
        
    }
    clearInterval(intervalID);
      tablica = [];
  }, 50);

  
}

I want to set styleResetElement if a signal does not appear at least 3 times because the button might me broken.
